# Remove ink mark from paper using OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image like this,

[image]

As you can see, there is a pen mark in the image. I want to remove that mark. How to do it in OpenCV.?

I tried converting it to HSV, creating a mask with blue range and removing it using the code.

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50]) 
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255]) 

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue , upper_blue ) 
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= mask)
```

It is not working as needed. All the text gets removed. How to fix this.?

Comment: Instead of `res = cv2.bitwise_and(...)`, you could just use `img[mask == 255] = (255, 255, 255)`. That will set all masked pixels to `(255, 255, 255)` (white), which is what you want to achieve, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take threshold of the first array  of image. It looks like this:

[image: first array]

Here it is clearly visible the difference in pixel values of the ink mark and the letters. After thresholding it looks like:

[image: thresholded image]

The ink mark can now be removed via closing. However it will reduce the size of letters as well. Therefore erosion is performed followed by a bitwise OR to obtain our mask without the ink mark.

[image: mask]

If however you want the letters to look like the original image you can store the mask in a numpy array of 255s and perform it bitwise OR with original image.

[image: result]

The full code I have used is:

```
img = cv2.imread('ink_mark.png')
wimg = img[:, :, 0]
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(wimg,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
erosion = cv2.erode(closing, kernel, iterations = 1)
mask = cv2.bitwise_or(erosion, thresh)
white = np.ones(img.shape,np.uint8)*255
white[:, :, 0] = mask
white[:, :, 1] = mask
white[:, :, 2] = mask
result = cv2.bitwise_or(img, white)

cv2.imshow('image', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You can see some gap in between pixels of some letters, just like in top of `e` in `Date`. Can it be removed.?

Comment: Use a bigger kernel size for erosion

Answer (score 2):

Try using inpaint. First create a mask of the ink:

```
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
lower_blue = np.array([100,50,50]) 
upper_blue = np.array([150,255,255]) 
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations = 4)
```

[image: mask]

Use the inpaint function to paint in areas where the mask it white. OpenCV will throw away the original pixels, and use guess which pixels should go there.

```
dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
```

[image]

Comment: Your code actually solves my problem, but you can see a small blurred effect over the text.